# MySQL Query Optimization with Temporary Tables

Tags: mysql, sql

**EDIT** These individual queries are part of a larger procedure that is being used to build a report in Excel that can be automatically refreshed by other users.

I am converting queries from SQL Server to MySQL. The query below pulls in about 1.6 million records.

```
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table_1
    AS
       (SELECT...
          FROM accounts a -- also a temporary table
              JOIN tdate d ON a.date1 <= d.date2
          WHERE PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT(d.date2, '%Y%m'), DATE_FORMAT(a.date1, '%Y%m')) >= 0
         );
```

Then it has to be updated from itself and joined to itself. Due to the limitations of MySQL, I need to duplicate the table two times. The `UPDATE` is where the query starts to take a long time.

```
    /* Create duplicate temp tables */
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table_2
    AS
       (SELECT * FROM table_1);

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table_3
    AS
       (SELECT * FROM table_2);

    /* UPDATE table_1 */
        UPDATE table_1 a
        JOIN
           (SELECT ...
                   SUM(ind_costs) as tcosts
            FROM table_2 b
                JOIN table_3 s ON b.id = s.id
            WHERE b.dperiod >= s.dperiod
            GROUP BY b.id, 
                     b.dperiod) z
        ON a.id = z.id
                 AND a.dperiod = z.dperiod
    SET a.tcosts = z.tcosts;
```

The query runs fine in SQL Server, I assume because I don't need to make 3 copies of the temporary table with 1.6 million rows to `UPDATE` and `JOIN` itself. This query runs extremely slow in MySQL. Any suggestions on how I could optimize this to run more efficiently? I am operating on MySQL Server 5.7.30

**EDIT** Finally, there is another query that follows the `UPDATE` which narrows the scope of the `SELECT`, `JOIN`s another table and filters with a `WHERE`. This is used in a report that gets exported to Excel and can be refreshed by other users.

```
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS table_2;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS table_3;

-- The final query results from the procedure
    SELECT  ...
    FROM table_1 a
        JOIN stats s ON a.state = s.state 
            AND a.column1 = s.column1
            AND a.column2 = s.column2
    WHERE a.dperiod = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m')
        AND a.costs < s.avg_costs
    ORDER BY period DESC;
```

The query takes a few seconds to run in SQL Server but I have let it run for more than an hour in MySQL and it still wasn't complete. I am looking for any ways that could potentially speed up the entire process. I realize that is a bit vague.  Thanks for your suggestions in advance.

**SOLUTION EDIT** I posted a solution that sped up the query from taking more than an hour (I never let it finish) to 4 minutes. Although not perfect this is far better than what I was working with. I would be open to other suggestions if people have improvements, however, I selected what worked for me for now.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help -- as would an explanation of what the logic should be doing.

Comment: Sorry, I realized I left off that I needed to then query the results after the final update to be exported for a report in Excel so the query wasn't the final component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although not perfect, what I have done so far has taken the query down from more than an hour (never full let it run) to about 4 min using `INDEX` on my specified `id` column and on my `period` column. My `id` column was unique to individuals and period represented a date in `'%Y%m'` format.

I utilized this method because those were common columns in `JOIN`, `WHERE`, and `GROUP BY` clauses. I stumbled upon this, either a *compound* or *covering index*, method reading SO and [this](https://blog.toadworld.com/2017/04/06/speed-up-your-queries-using-the-covering-index-in-mysql).

I created the index on each temp table that I made because I was unsure if the index carried over from each table. When I tried to do it only on `table_1` it was still very slow so I kept them at each creation.

**EDIT** Upon testing, I only needed to make the index for `table_1` and for `table_2`. It appears that the index was copied from `table_2` to `table_3`.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table_1
    AS
       (SELECT...
          FROM accounts a -- also a temporary table
              JOIN tdate d ON a.date1 <= d.date2
          WHERE PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT(d.date2, '%Y%m'), DATE_FORMAT(a.date1, '%Y%m')) >= 0
         );

/*
#############################################
added index here and for the first temp table
#############################################
*/
ALTER TABLE table_1
   ADD INDEX (id, reporting_period);
```

```
 /* Create duplicate temp tables */
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table_2
    AS
       (SELECT * FROM table_1);

-- additional index
ALTER TABLE table_2
   ADD INDEX (placedetail_id, reporting_period);

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE table_3
    AS
       (SELECT * FROM table_2);

    /* UPDATE table_1 */
        UPDATE table_1 a
        JOIN
           (SELECT ...
                   SUM(ind_costs) as tcosts
            FROM table_2 b
                JOIN table_3 s ON b.id = s.id
            WHERE b.dperiod >= s.dperiod
            GROUP BY b.id, 
                     b.dperiod) z
        ON a.id = z.id
                 AND a.dperiod = z.dperiod
    SET a.tcosts = z.tcosts;

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS table_2;
    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS table_3;
```

```
-- The final query results from the procedure
    SELECT  ...
    FROM table_1 a
        JOIN stats s ON a.state = s.state 
            AND a.column1 = s.column1
            AND a.column2 = s.column2
    WHERE a.dperiod = DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m')
        AND a.costs < s.avg_costs
    ORDER BY period DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need a temporary table at all?  Just run a single query.  I think you want:

```
select t.*,
       sum(ind_costs) over (partition by id order by dperiod) as running_ind_costs
from table_1 t1;
```

You could include this in the original definition of the table.